# String Manipulation Comparison

Tags: java, string

**EDITED**

I have this kind of string

1. `"A-B-C-D"`
2. `"B-C-A"`
3. `"D-A"`
4. `"B-A-D"`
5. `"D-A-B-C"`

Now my problem is if the user input has a value of `"A-C"` or `"C-A"` the numbers 1,2,5 will be my output because the those numbers has a value "A-C" if for example the user has a input value of either of this three `"A-B-D"`,`"B-A-D"`,`"A-D-B"` the the output will be 1,4,5. hope it clears the question

**Note:**
the search sequence depends on user input and i want it to be more efficient because I have 10 thousand of data I don't want to use as much loop as possible.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you could just split each character using the delimiter `-` and then iterate through them and see if each string in the set of strings contains all of the characters.

Comment: i will try your suggestion

Comment: @DevfaR: Please clarify whether or not you will *only* be searching for two-character strings like "A-C", or if you will be searching for longer strings like "A-D-B". It is the source of much speculation below -- If you are only searching for two-character strings then it is sufficient to just see if the input string contains both characters, whether or not its reversed is irrelevant. If you are searching for longer strings, though, then a different algorithm that enforces the search order is required.

Comment: okay i will reedit my question sorry because it's misleading

Comment: Wow, everyone got down voted.

Comment: i did'nt down voted any of the answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might change based on you needs to have the `String` in the exact pattern you have it or not, but REALLY simply...

```
public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("1. " + matches("A-B-C-D"));
        System.out.println("2. " + matches("B-C-A"));
        System.out.println("3. " + matches("D-A"));
        System.out.println("4. " + matches("B-A-D"));
        System.out.println("5. " + matches("D-A-B-C"));
    }

    public static boolean matches(String value) {

        return value.contains("A") && value.contains("C");

    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
1. true
2. true
3. false
4. false
5. true
```

**Extended example using variable matchers**

So, the basic idea is to provide some kind of list of values to be matched against.  This example simply uses a `String` varargs (or `String` array), but it wouldn't be hard to make it use something like `List`

```
public class Simple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] match = new String[]{"A", "D", "C"};
        System.out.println("1. " + matches("A-B-C-D", match));
        System.out.println("2. " + matches("B-C-A", match));
        System.out.println("3. " + matches("D-A", match));
        System.out.println("4. " + matches("B-A-D", match));
        System.out.println("5. " + matches("D-A-B-C", match));
    }

    public static boolean matches(String value, String... matches) {

        boolean doesMatch = true;
        for (String match : matches) {

            if (!value.contains(match)) {
                doesMatch = false;
                break;
            }

        }

        return doesMatch;

    }
}
```

This outputs...

```
1. true
2. false
3. false
4. false
5. true
```

Comment: Mine looks cooler. ;) Hahaha.

Comment: @DummyCode I like the reg-exp version, might need to give that a +1

Comment: Yay! Hahaha. Already +1'd you.

Comment: i voted up your code but i need to try this first since i will have longer search sequence :)

Comment: @DevfaR Remember, this is an EXAMPLE, proof of concept.  You may need to make your own adjustments to it ;)

Comment: I don't mind the down vote so much, but do us all a favor and let us know why...how else are we suppose to grow and learn if all you do is troll :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer if i have dynamic input values how will i compare more than 2 values because the method only compares 2 value :)

Comment: You could provide a list of values to compare.  Let me extend the example...

Comment: @DevfaR Added extending example. Let me know if you have any problems - remember, this is just a simple example.  Depending on your needs, you might need something more sophisticated...

Answer (score 2):

Use an array and go through each index and see if it contains "C-A" or "A-C" then if it does print the number.

```
       String stringArray[] = {"A-B-C-D", "B-C-A", "D-A", "B-A-D", "D-A-B-C"};
       for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
           String pattern = ".*C-.*A.*";
           String pattern2 = ".*A-.*C.*";
           if(stringArray[i].matches(pattern) || stringArray[i].matches(pattern2))
               System.out.println(i + 1);
      }
```

Comment: This would not work for string 5.

Comment: @andy256 I will update with a regex.

Comment: @DummyCode The question is misleading, the OP is looking for `A` and `C` in the same `String` not just `A-C` or `C-A`...I think `stringArray[i].contains("A") && stringArray[i].contains("C")` will give the results the OP is looking for...

Comment: sorry if i can't explain it well to clarify my question if for example
i have A-D-C and even if compare it to C-A it will be true because the string A-D-C has C-A in it well i think i need to parse it 1 by 1 to detect if it contains that string

Comment: @DevfaR But that string does not contain `C-A`...

Comment: @DummyCode Strictly speaking, you are right.  I think the OP is seeking `A` AND `C`

Comment: @DummyCode yes the code you provide is correct but thats not what i want to achieve if i split the string and detect if A-D-C has C-A with it?

Comment: So you want to verify that it contains A AND C?

Comment: The OP means that finding a string X-Y-Z in A-B-C-D-E means that X-Y-Z or Z-Y-X appear in order in A-B-C-D-E, possibly with other values in between.

Comment: @JasonC Not according to #5.  The OP's requirements state the they should be matches for #1, #2 and #5.  #5 is `D-A-B-C`, where `A` and `C` aren't adjacent...

Comment: @DummyCode It's still a "little" off, but I like the use of Regular Expression, makes it more flexible...

Comment: @MadProgrammer That is why I qualified it with "possibly with other values in between". Sorry if it was poorly worded.

Comment: @JasonC Sorry, must have missed that :P

Comment: In any case we'll have to wait until the OP clarifies whether he's only searching for two-character sequences, or if he needs to search for longer sequences.

Comment: i will reedit my question because it will have longer search sequence depending on user input but i will try this code if it fits my need

Comment: BTW, `".*" + "A-B-C".replace("-", ".*") + ".*"` can be used to generate the pattern for any input.

Comment: this is okay but my values is dynamic i need to compare sometimes more than two but it's okay now i used @MadProgrammer it's much simpler to implement thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Why would you use regex for such a simple task? There are much faster alternatives.

Comment: @JoshM That way bAllCap would not pass.

Answer (score 1):

Call this function on every string you wish to check.  If it returns true, add that string to your result set.

```
boolean matches(String s, char[] chars) {
    for(char c : chars) {
        if (s.indexOf(c) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My impression is the OP was trying to find the subsequence *in order*.

Comment: @JasonC "I should get the numbers 1,2,5; because those numbers has C and A in them". The behavior when more than 3 characters are being searched for is not defined in the question, however with only two, all orderings are either forwards or reversed if they both exist.

Comment: Yes, I agree that his question is unfortunately ambiguous due to his example only having 2 characters.

Comment: He *does* want more than 2, but not in order.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is pretty much identical to the accepted answer.

Comment: To add what information?  This approach works for detecting any number of desired chars in a candidate string regardless of ordering.  That's exactly what you just said the OP is looking for and it's what the OP has accepted.

Comment: To add no information. SO just doesn't let you change votes after a certain amount of time unless an answer is edited. I've arbitrarily added some indentation to your code to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: This applies to an older version of the OP that was unclear about finding the sequence in order; and so this searches for sequences in order, which isn't correct now.*

There are many options. Below I outline one approach that tokenizes the strings first, and another that uses a simple regex generated from the input string.

**Approach 1: Parsing Strings**

Start by parsing each `String` into an array of substrings, that will make this all easier to work with. You may want to parse each of the strings when you originally read them instead of every time you need to:

```
String myString = "A-B-C-D";
String[] sequence = myString.split("-");
```

Next, consider using an `List<String>` instead of a `String[]`, because it will make the rest of this a bit easier (you'll see). So, instead of the above:

```
String myString = "A-B-C-D";
List<String> sequence = Arrays.asList(myString.split("-"));
```

Now the problem becomes checking if two of these arrays match:

```
public static boolean containsSequence (List<String> searchIn, List<String> searchFor) {
}
```

You need to check both directions, but you can simply reverse the array and reduce this problem further to just checking the forward direction (there are certainly ways to do this and avoid the copy but they can get complicated and it's only worth it if you have high performance requirements):

```
public static boolean containsSequence (List<String> searchIn, List<String> searchFor) {
    // first check forward
    if (containsSequenceForward(searchIn, searchFor))
        return true;
    // now check in reverse
    List<String> reversedSearchFor = new ArrayList<String>(searchFor);
    Collections.reverse(reversedSearchFor);
    return containsSequenceForward(searchIn, reversedSearchFor);
}

public static boolean containsSequenceForward (List<String> searchIn, List<String> searchFor) {
}

// usage example:
public static void example () {
    List<String> searchIn = Arrays.asList("D-A-B-C".split("-"));
    List<String> searchFor = Arrays.asList("A-C".split("-"));
    boolean contained = containsSequence(searchIn, searchFor);
}
```

Now you just need to implement `containsSequenceForward`. I'd like you to do this yourself, but I will provide an algorithm as a hint:

1. Start at the beginning of searchIn and searchFor.
2. Go through searchIn one element at a time.
3. When you find the current element of searchFor in searchIn, advance searchFor to next element.
4. If you hit the end of searchFor you've found the sequence.
5. If you hit the end of searchIn but not searchFor, then the sequence doesn't match.

Now you have the ability to check if one sequence contains another in any order. To apply it to your entire collection, I recommend preparsing all of the strings into a `List<String>` once at the start, then you can go through each of those using the above algorithm.

There are many alternative options. For example, you could use `indexOf` on `searchIn` to find the each element in `searchFor` and make sure the indices are in increasing order.

**Approach 2: Regular Expressions**

Another option here is to use a regular expression to find the search sequence in the source string. You can build the regular expression dynamically from the search sequence quite easily:

```
String searchIn = "D-C-B-A";
String searchFor = "C-A";

String searchForPattern = searchFor.replace("-", ".*"); // yields "C.*A"
if (searchIn.matches(".*" + searchForPattern + ".*"))
   /* then it matches forwards */;
```

Then to match in reverse, if the forward match fails, you can just reverse `searchFor` and repeat:

```
String searchForReverse = new StringBuilder(searchFor).reverse().toString();
String searchForReversePattern = searchForReverse.replace("-", ".*"); // yields "A.*C"
if (searchIn.matches(".*" + searchForReversePattern + ".*"))
   /* then it matches backwards */;
```

Note that this particular regex solution assumes that each element is only one character long.

Also both of the above approaches assume case-sensitive matches -- to make the first case-insensitive I would just convert the strings to lowercase before parsing. For the second you can use a case-insensitive regex.

Hope that helps. Work it out on a piece of paper if you have to.

The general take home point here is it helps to reduce these problems to their smallest components first.

Comment: Note that according to the OP's requirements, the two characters need not be adjacent.  Just `String#indexOf` or `String#contians` is sufficient.

Comment: @Aurand The algorithm I outlined does not require adjacency. Additionally, my impression of the OP's request (based on the fact that he explicitly mentioned searching in reverse order) is that the subsequence must appear in order, so `indexOf` or `contains` alone would not do the job, you would have to check positions as well.

Comment: i already solved the problem without splitting the string i used @MadProgrammer code anyway thanks to your answer maybe some user will find this relevant to their problem :)